# Newsletter subscription at the checkout review

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer, onepage-checkout, newsletter

Expected functionality: user checks the "Subscribe" checkbox in the OnePage Checkout's review step and is subscribed to the newsletter.

So far I have managed to target the right event (after submitting checkout form):

***config.xml***

```
<events>        
    <checkout_submit_all_after>
        <observers>
            <checkout_newsletter>
                <class>News_Custom_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>assignNewsletter</method>
            </checkout_newsletter>
        </observers>
    </checkout_submit_all_after>   
</events>
```

***info.phtml contains***

```
<div class="text-left mt10 mb30">
     <div class="input-checkbox">
        <input id="subscribe_newsletter" type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" value="1" checked="checked">
        <label for="is_subscribed">Subscribe for newsletter</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Observer.php***

```
public function assignNewsletter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    $quote = $event->getQuote();

    if ($observer->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)) {
        Mage::log('got here');
        Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($quote->getCustomerEmail());
    } else {
        Mage::log($observer->getRequest()->getParams());
    }
}
```

What happends is that `$observer->getRequest()->getParams()` only contains shipping method. So the issue is to pass/capture the data from checkout view to observer.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- First, make sure that you template code iss inside a `<form>` tag.

  ```
  <form action="" id="checkout-review" onsubmit="return false;">
      ...
      <div class="text-left mt10 mb30">
          <div class="input-checkbox">
              <input id="subscribe_newsletter" type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" value="1" checked="checked">
              <label for="is_subscribed">Subscribe for newsletter</label>
          </div>
      </div>
      ...
  </form>
  ```
- add first observer to `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder` to store user input in checkout session

  ```
  public function checkoutSaveOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
  {
      $subscribe = $observer->getEvent()
          ->getControllerAction()
          ->getRequest()
          ->getParam('is_subscribed', 0);

      Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setIsSubscribed($subscribe);

      return $this;
  }
  ```
- add second observer to `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after` to subscribe user after order is placed

  ```
  public function checkoutSaveOrderAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
  {
      $subscribe = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getIsSubscribed();

      if ((bool)$subscribe) {
          $email = $observer->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail();
          Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
      }
      return $this;
  }
  ```

Comment: which one is the better answer, I see you edited both. Appreciate it. Currently having trouble where the input field is not passed, does the form need to be around the final review submit button too?

Comment: @snh_nl Wich one? What do you mean? The form has just to be arrond your input field. Test with RWD theme ... maybe you have a different behavoir?

Comment: Sorry misread your question as an answer ;) got it working

Comment: @snh_nl if it was useful to you, please leave some feedback :)